# NSUserDefaults and registerDefault, a standard behavior?

Tags: cocoa

I need to store a numeric parameter in NSUserDefault, this parameter must be as default 1
So i write this code :

```
NSNumber *one = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];    
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      one,@"my-param",
                      nil];

[def registerDefaults:dict];
```

This parameter has a bind over a checkbox in IB so i can check that it's correctly set and when i start my app i see checkbox with state "on".

On the other side i must check this value programmatically so... i do something like :

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger my_param = [defaults integerForKey:@"my-param"];
```

I excepted that since the value is not set by the user this function return value that i set as default (in my case "1") but with my surprise i found that if value has never  been set by user it returns 0 ... as you can understand this's terrible :P because now i can't understand if this "0" is obtained by user choice of this's a consequence of a non-set value... how can i write code to manage this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store the numeric values in **NSUserDefaults** you can simply directly use as follows:

To set the integer Value in NSUserDefault use as follows below:

```
NSInteger lInteger = 10; 

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:lInteger forKey:@"integerkey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

And to use that NSInteger value anywhere in your project use as below:

NSInteger linteger = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"integerkey"];

And i didnt understand your question exactly, but anyhow i think this above code may help you.